# Query document based on field's value containing backslash using regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query DB with documments similar to one presented below.

```
{
  "_id":"5b9bd1b947c7471038399a39",
  "subdir":"ge\\pt02\\kr02_20180824\\kr02_2018091log\\0010796ab5",
}
```

How to filter all documments starting with: `ge\\pt02\\kr02`

I tried many different approaches,
for example:

```
{"subdir": {"$regex": "pt02\\kr02*"}}
```

but I cannot figure out how to prepare a correct filter:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to escape the backslash there. Also since you want to select only the documents starting with this pattern, you need to group the regex into a parenthesis and prefix the group with caret. This gives us the following regex:

```
let pattern = "^(ge\\\\pt02\\\\kr02)";

{"subdir": {"$regex": pattern}}
```

[Demo:](https://regex101.com/r/z6rYBK/2)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to escape the slashes.

Here is a working example:

```
db.test1.insert({"subdir":"ge\\pt02\\kr02_20180824\\k2_2018091log\\0010796ab5"})

db.test1.find({"subdir": { $regex: "^ge\\\\pt02\\\\kr02"}})
```

This prints out:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba28194fbb45cb9f7c58b18"), "subdir" : "ge\\pt02\\kr02_20180824\\kr02_2018091log\\0010796ab5" }
```